# Resumable.js don't send binary chunks

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I'm using Resumable.js to upload files but the problem is that i'receive all chunks information and not the binary chunks this is the list of parameters sended during upload

```
data[resumableRelativePath]=Video.mov,  
data[resumableChunkNumber]=13,  
data[resumableChunkSize]=2097152,  
data[resumableIdentifier]=27349639-Video.mov,  
data[resumableTotalSize]=27349639,  
data[resumableFilename]=Video.mov
```